# Angular 9 Configure Lazy Loaded Route

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I'm trying to configure my lazy-loaded route using forRoot method. I get the following error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: ASSERTION ERROR: NgModule '[object Object]' is not a subtype of 'NgModuleType'. [Expected=> null != null <=Actual]
>   Error: ASSERTION ERROR: NgModule '[object Object]' is not a subtype of 'NgModuleType'. [Expected=> null != null <=Actual]

Here's a link to my sample code: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vlsxqu

Comment: I don't really understand why you want to do a `forRoot` on a lazy loaded module.
The `forRoot` is for modules that should be shared i.e. not routed to so that you can get access to the same instance for services which the modules provide.

Comment: to me it seems bug from angular. I guess you should open issue in angular repo.

Comment: @Nico makes sense. I just need a way to configure my module.

Comment: Your given link seems to be broken! However does this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63189323/13440669 answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

In the app.module.ts remove `.forRoot()`

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule, 
    FormsModule , 
    RouterModule.forRoot([{
      path: 'lazy',
      loadChildren: () =>
          import("./lazy/lazy.module").then(m => m.LazyModule)
    }, {
      path: "**",
      redirectTo: "lazy"
    }], 
    {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules})
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

also in lazy.module.ts remove the `static forRoot()` method completely

Comment: Come on I don’t just throw a forRoot at the end for fun.

Comment: But it seems you did! otherwise you've made a complete example...

Comment: The goal is to make a minimum reproducible example for others to see the error, dumping a project of a 2K lines here does not help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about you but my problem was a multiple duplications of my code that caused this problem.