# Angular 9 Universal and lazy loaded routes

Tags: angular, angular-universal

Quick question; I can't find any documentation on the issue.
In previous versions on Angular Universal, to render lazy loaded routes in **view source** you had to include `ModuleMapLoaderModule` in the **app.server.module.ts**.

In Angular 9, it appears you don't have to do that if you are not using strings for `loadChildren`.
I have a new project and I have set up lazy loading like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./brands/brands.module').then((m) => m.BrandsModule),
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' },
];
```

If I view the page source, I cannot see my **BrandsComponent** but if I change the routing to this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: BrandsComponent,
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' },
];
```

Viewing the page source shows the **BrandsComponent** which tells me lazy loading is not working.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Lazy loading basics](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#lazy-loading-basics) in the document is kinda misleading.

You should read [Step-by-step setup](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#step-by-step-setup) carefully.

I think the structure should be like the following:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./brands/brands.module').then((m) => m.BrandsModule),
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' },
];
```

**brands-routing.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BrandsComponent } from './brands.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: BrandsComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class BrandsRoutingModule { }
```

**brands.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrandsRoutingModule } from './brands-routing.module';
import { BrandsComponent } from './brands.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrandsRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [BrandsComponent]
})
export class BrandsModule { }
```

Comment: It wasn't this, I actually had a resolver on the brands route that was causing an issue, but this is a good clear answer that will help most people, so I have accepted it

Comment: @r3plica You'd better post another answer that fixes your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't get what exactly you changed in the original code snippet?